# About symbols size in physics package

Tags: symbols, size, physics

Is it possible to change symbols size?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What is the symbol. Please, can you explain more clear your question?

Comment: The `physics` package provides lots of symbols. Which ones would you like to increase in size?

Comment: You can use the `relsize` package with `\mathlarger` to make symbols larger. However, I do *not* recommend using the `physics` package.

Comment: Thanks for your replay!